# Linux apache2 performance issues

Tags: php, linux, apache, dns, server

I am really confused right now. I have extreme performance issues with my websites running on apache2 on a linux VM server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS‬).

I'm not sure if it's a PHP problem or a general performance issue or just a bad DNS configuration. I am guessing that it has something to do with the DNS configuration. If I want to access my website I get a 504 Bad Gateway Error but I can easily access the server via SSH and the cpu load isn't even over 1%.

I am kinda new to server administration and in an effort to resolve my problem I read so many different tutorials and guides that I am really confused at this point.

I'd be really thankful for any advise on properly setting up my DNS or general tipps.

Comment: This is not a performance issue. You should check your webserver configuration.

Comment: Check Apaches access log. If you get too many simultaneous requests, Apache can still go on it's knees without the server having much of a load. Other than that, it's totally impossible for us to help you since there are _way_ too many unknowns.